# How to create a linked list sorted by multiple data types

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list sorted by 2 different data types stored in a pointer to a tree.  The structures are:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
   int label;
   long count;
   struct TreeNode *left;
   struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct ListNode {
   TreeNode *ptr;
   struct ListNode *next;
   struct ListNode *prev;
} ListNode;
```

I'm using a function called addNode which sorts the linked list nodes with the following rules:

```
1. Smallest Count First
2. Smallest Label First
```

How do I correctly update my header whenever these 2 conditions aren't met?

```
    ListNode * prev = NULL;

    while( (*head) != NULL && (*head) -> ptr -> count < new -> ptr -> count){
      prev = (*head);
      (*head) = (*head) -> next; 
    }

    while( (*head) != NULL && (*head) -> ptr -> label < new -> ptr -> label){
      prev = (*head);
      (*head) = (*head) -> next;
    }

    new -> next = (*head);  
    prev -> next = new; 
    return; 
}
```

GDB Error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400d6e in addNode (head=0x602010, new=0x602030) at list.c:84
84      prev -> next = new;
```

Example: Each `label` contains an ASCII character and each `count` contains the frequency of that character from a string that was read in earlier.

For the string `test` the desired list would look like:
(Key: |Label:Count| )

|10:1| -> |e:1| -> |s:1| -> |t:2| -> NULL

Comment: `(*head) = (*head) -> next;` This changes the list destructively.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY While I am convinced that you are right, I think that a programmer who made the mistake in the first place might need a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Hitmarcurse What kind of error do you get? Compiler error (which)? Runtime error(which symptoms)? Unexpected behaviour observed via debugger(which)? Can you provide a [mcve]? And please take the [tour] to get the badge.

Comment: I added an answer that includes a check for reaching the end of a list in AddNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, traverse the list till you find a node with not less `count`, then again traverse from there while the `node->count` is equal to the `newNode->count` and `node->label` is less than `new->label`. Insert the node at the position you have reached.

Below is the implementation of the addNode function

```
void addNode(ListNode ** head, ListNode * newNode){
    ListNode *node = *head;
    if(*head != NULL) {
        while(node && node->ptr->count < newNode->ptr->count) {
            node = node->next;
        }

        while(node && node->ptr->count == newNode->ptr->count && 
               node->ptr->label < newNode->ptr->label) {
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    if(node != NULL && node->prev != NULL) {
            node->prev->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = node;
            newNode->prev = node->prev;
            node->prev = newNode;
    }
    else if(*head == NULL){
         newNode->next = *head;
         newNode->prev = NULL;
         *head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        node = *head;
        while(node->next) node = node->next;
        node->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->prev = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still causes a seg fault at: if(node->prev != NULL) {

Comment: @Hitmarcurse added condition to prevent SEG fault

Comment: `ListNode *node = *head;` is fine, you only need `(*head)` to protect the *operator precedence* on dereference.

Comment: this still just results in a seg fault at the first while loop

Comment: well code works fine on my machine... there may be an error somewhere else in the code...you didn't post the full code!

Comment: @Hitmarcurse - This code fails (seg fault) if node is advanced to the end of the list, where node then becomes NULL. This only happens if the data used results in a node being appended to the end of a non-empty list.

Comment: @RajeevSingh - This code fails (seg fault) if node is advanced to the end of the list, where node then becomes NULL. This only happens if the data used results in a node being appended to the end of a non-empty list.

Comment: @RajeevSingh -  The last else (node == NULL, head != NULL), needs to set newNode->next = NULL, and newNode->prev to the last node in the list. In my answer, I keep track of the prior node with ListNode *prev, to deal with this case. Try using the test code in my answer with your addNode() to test for this, which will catch this problem when printing the sorted list in backwards order.

Comment: @RajeevSingh - The else if(head == NULL), needs to set newNode->next to NULL.

Comment: edited condition `if(head == NULL)` to `if(*head == NULL)` which was wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer to pointer to node simplifies the code:

```
void AddNode(ListNode **head, ListNode *new)
{
ListNode **ppCurr = head;
ListNode *prev = NULL;
    while( (*ppCurr) != NULL &&
          ((*ppCurr)->ptr->count <  new->ptr->count ||
          ((*ppCurr)->ptr->count == new->ptr->count &&
           (*ppCurr)->ptr->label <  new->ptr->label))){
        prev = *ppCurr;
        ppCurr = &((*ppCurr)->next);
    }
    new->next = *ppCurr;
    new->prev = prev;
    if((*ppCurr) != NULL)
        (*ppCurr)->prev = new;
    *ppCurr = new;
}
```

This is the test code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct TreeNode {
   int label;
   long count;
   struct TreeNode *left;
   struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct ListNode {
   TreeNode *ptr;
   struct ListNode *next;
   struct ListNode *prev;
} ListNode;

void AddNode(ListNode **head, ListNode *new)
{
ListNode **ppCurr = head;
ListNode *prev = NULL;
    while( (*ppCurr) != NULL &&
          ((*ppCurr)->ptr->count <  new->ptr->count ||
          ((*ppCurr)->ptr->count == new->ptr->count &&
           (*ppCurr)->ptr->label <  new->ptr->label))){
        prev = *ppCurr;
        ppCurr = &((*ppCurr)->next);
    }
    new->next = *ppCurr;
    new->prev = prev;
    if((*ppCurr) != NULL)
        (*ppCurr)->prev = new;
    *ppCurr = new;
}

int main(void)
{
TreeNode at[8] = {{'e',3, NULL, NULL},{'g',1, NULL, NULL},
                  {'h',3, NULL, NULL},{'b',3, NULL, NULL},
                  {'c',1, NULL, NULL},{'d',2, NULL, NULL},
                  {'a',2, NULL, NULL},{'f',1, NULL, NULL}};
ListNode an[8] = {{at+0, NULL, an+1},{at+1, an+0, an+2},
                  {at+2, an+1, an+3},{at+3, an+2, an+4},
                  {at+4, an+3, an+5},{at+5, an+4, an+6},
                  {at+6, an+5, an+7},{at+7, an+6, NULL}};
ListNode *head = NULL;
ListNode *node;
ListNode *prev;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(an)/sizeof(an[0]) ; i++)
        AddNode(&head, an+i);
    node = head;        /* print list forwards */
    while(node){
        printf("%c %u\n", node->ptr->label, node->ptr->count);
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");       /* print list backwards */
    while(prev){
        printf("%c %u\n", prev->ptr->label, prev->ptr->count);
        prev = prev->prev;
    }
    return(0);
}
```